# GetOpt Long processing similar input names

Tags: perl

I'm running a perl script with a lot of input options, one of them being:

```
        'errorcode=s{1,}'  => \@ecodes,
```

I have a die at the end of the GetOptions if anything entered doesn't match the input.  However if I input '--ecode 500' the program runs.

Why isn't the script dying?  If I try something else like '--testing 123' it does die.

Comment: Can you please show all of the relevant code and how you're running it? I can't reproduce your issue. Be aware that Getopt::Long supports [abbreviated options](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Case-and-abbreviations) by default, so depending on what other options you've defined, `--error`, `--err`, and `--e` could all work.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem? Hard to see where you messed up if you don't show us!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a option with a required argument such as

```
"foo=s" => \$foo,
```

and that you did something like

```
program --foo --ecode 500
```

which puts `--ecode` in `$foo` and `500` in `@ARGV`.

```
$ perl -MGetopt::Long -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   GetOptions("foo=s" => \$foo)
      or die "usage\n";
   say "ok <$foo> <@ARGV>";
' -- \
   --ecode 500
Unknown option: ecode
usage

$ perl -MGetopt::Long -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   GetOptions("foo=s" => \$foo)
      or die "usage\n";
   say "ok <$foo> <@ARGV>";
' -- \
   --foo --ecode 500
ok <--ecode> <500>
```

Comment: Good guess, although it doesn't explain why `--testing 123` would work while `--ecode 500` doesn't.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, That's simple: They did more than just changing `--ecode 503` to `--testing 123`. `--ecode 503` was probably part of a larger command line in another script/program, whereas they probably passed `--testing 123` straight to the program from the command line.

Comment: This can also be controlled by using the colon, `foo:s` and then a value is required on the command line.

Comment: @zdim, You are describing `=s`. A colon will make the value *optional*, causing `GetOptions("foo:s" => \$foo)` to fail as desired for `--foo --ecode 500`. Of course, that's only a valid solution if `--foo`'s value is truly optional.

Comment: @ikegami Oh, of course. In my mind it requires a value on the command line (to be correctly supplied by the user) since it otherwise actually fails, but interface wise it's the other way round. Sorry for noise.  The second time I reverse things in this Q :(